# Delay access to property in ionic 2 class

Tags: android, angular, storage, ionic2

I have a non static traduction file that I periodically get from a server. I cannont change the format of the file.

When I a new page is instanciate in my Ionic App I set `this.traductions` from a value in storage. See constructor below :

```
constructor(storage: Storage, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public commandeService: CommandeService, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public translate: TranslateService) {

    this.categorie = this.navParams.get('categorie');

    storage.get('boissons').then((StringBoissons) => {
      var boissons: Array<any> = JSON.parse(StringBoissons);
      this.boissons = boissons.filter(
        (value) => {
          return value.tboi_id == this.categorie.tboi_id;
        });
      }
    );
    storage.get('traductions').then((val) => {
      this.traductions = JSON.parse(val);
    });
    this.commande = commandeService.getCommande();
    this.translate = translate;
  }
```

Then my View call `getTraduction(...)`

```
  getTraduction(table, champ, id, objet) {
    var traduction = this.traductions.find( (value) => {
      return value.trad_table == table && value.trad_champ == champ && value.trad_code_langue == this.translate.currentLang && value.trad_id_item == objet[id];
    });
    if ( traduction && traduction.trad_texte  )
      return traduction.trad_texte;
    else
      return objet[champ];
  }
```

Everything works fine in browser preview but on device I get a

> Cannot call method 'find' of null
>       at t.getTraduction

I think it is due to asynchronous results but I can't quite get my head around it and figure how to solve this.

Thanks in advance for any insight

Answer (score 0):

OK quite dumb question actually Sylvain :
You should have put your getTraduction function in a provider.

```
@Injectable()
export class TraductionDynaService {

  traductions;

  constructor(
    public storage: Storage,
    public http: Http,
    public translate: TranslateService,
    ) {
    storage.get('traductions').then((val) => {
      this.traductions = JSON.parse(val);
    });
  }

  getTraduction(table, champ, id, objet) {
    var traduction = this.traductions.find( (value) => {
      return value.trad_table == table && value.trad_champ == champ && value.trad_code_langue == this.translate.currentLang && value.trad_id_item == objet[id];
    });
    if ( traduction && traduction.trad_texte  )
      return traduction.trad_texte;
    else
      return objet[champ];
  }

}
```

And it worked like a charm. `getTraduction(...)` could even return a promise to handle when traduction is null or undefined...